# Custom UIImagePickerController View Not working

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to make a custom ImagePicker (camera) in my view controller.

Here the code:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Instantiate the UIImagePickerController instance
        self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        // Configure the UIImagePickerController instance
        self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

        // Make us the delegate for the UIImagePickerController
        self.picker.delegate = self;

        // Set the frames to be full screen
        CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        self.view.frame = screenFrame;
        self.picker.view.frame = screenFrame;

        // Set this VC's view as the overlay view for the UIImagePickerController
        self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.view;
    }
    return self;
}
```

What I have is a black page with the button I've created, and nothing more. When I press Take Photo button, it does take a real photo.
So my problem is that the UIImagePicker is not showing camera capture on my view.

Can anyone help me please on that. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the proper delegate method to show the image after it has been taken. Something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *myPhotoData = [[NSData alloc] init];
myPhotoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5); // compressionQuality between 0.0 and 1.0 higher being less compression
myPhotoOutlet.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myPhotoData]; // myPhotoOutlet is an UIImageView outlet on your screen
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I did it already ! My problem is when I set the VC view as the Overlay of the UIImagePickerController. I got the VC View without the UiImagePickerController. So when I deactivate this the UIImagePickeController works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add in your .h file a delegate declaration :

```
@interface YourViewcontroller : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

and you have to implement the delegate method in your .m file to get your image :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *newImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // and then you affect your image in your image view
   UIImageView *yourImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)];
   yourImageView.image=newImage;
}
```

i hope that help you !

Comment: I did it already ! My problem is when I set the VC view as the Overlay of the UIImagePickerController. I got the VC View without the UiImagePickerController. So when I deactivate this the UIImagePickerController works as usual.